# Portable python installation inside git repository

Tags: python, git, repository

Our Team (<10 People) is using a git repo to share a complete python environment (no venv) alongside every project in history. We use the repo to organize and archive our prototyping code. We use Windows-10 and python-3.11.4

```
our_repo/
├─ .git/
├─ shared_python/
│  ├─ Lib/
│  │  ├─ site-packages/
│  ├─ pip/
│  ├─ python.exe
├─ subproject_A/
│  ├─ src/..
│  ├─ data/..
├─ subproject_B/
│  ├─ src/..
│  ├─ data/..
..
```

The main reasons/rules for that were:

- the python executable and packages are inside /shared_python
- no need to deal with the python installation when switching branches or subprojects, just run the code.
- having to clone and maintain only one giant repository
- subprojects do not interact with each other
- no need to care about backwards compatibility or module management for a given subproject or branch
- development happens on a individual feature branch (usually only one person working on that)
- finished subproject branches are merged to master after development if no additional packages have been installed.
- shared_python/ is added to PATH for every repo-user

This is probably not the best and safest solution. We messed up the python installation once, so i want to introduce a cleaner and safer approach to manage our code.
But i dont know the best practices.

My idea so far is to just kick out the python and keep the structure the same. Aditionally, a requirements.txt is added to each subproject. But this would force the user to install packages first before being able to run something. I guess this is especially annoying when switching the branch

Is there a approach that offers the same "checkout & run" convenience?

Comment: "checkout & run" is for users and should be handled by some kind of deployment strategy. Developers need to understand the environment they're working in and if they can't handle more than "checkout & run" they need better training.

Comment: What about that: install Python/Anaconda/pip, clone/checkout, install requirements, run? If necessary, you can create a setup scripts people execute once after cloning the repo.